# How to remove whitespaces in front/end of a string in Android

Tags: android, string, strip

Assuming I have a String like this one in Android:

" This is an example String "

and i want to make it become:

"This is an example String"

I tried to use the split() but is not found in Android, is there any other method i'm not getting?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a string like this

```
String str = " This is an example String ";
```

then use the `trim()` method :

```
str.trim();
```

that's it!
The method automatically removes spaces in front and back